# Catch automatic mail return with php mail function

Tags: php, email, response, system

I'm using the function "mail" to send an email to an user in php. The information in this email needs to be only known in the email (not stocked on the server).

But some of the users have, for some reasons, an invalid email. When you try to send an email to an unknown address, you receive an automatic email from "Mail delivery system".

The idea is that I want to catch this email to be able to manage this situation.
Is there any way to do this in php ? Or is it possible to test if an email is reachable ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have been [using this library](https://packagist.org/packages/voku/bounce-mail-handler) in a few projects and it does the job of handling bounces fairly well. No handler like these can be made to interpret bounce email 100% correct since some MTA:s do not follow the RFC standards, and there are other libraries available out there as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It seems to be what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, I'm using an older version of php (5.3). I'm going to search a similar library for my version. If someone knows one, is it possible to share it here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I doubt you will find a maintained lib compatible with 5.3. I possible, push the project up to at least 7.1 since all previous versions have reached their end of life.
https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php
Mark the thread as answered if you feel the last reply is close enough to what you where looking fore.